# How do I scale the images on my blog's slideshow to fit a slide bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, blogger

I put a slideshow on my Blogger (I downloaded a theme with slideshow) and I want to edit this theme. I'm stuck on the picture size of this slide.

I found this code:

```
var slider1 = new skewSlider('#main-slider', {
    height: 450,
    imgAlign: 'xMidYMid slice',
    slidePercent: 50,
    visibleSiblings: 1,
    navigationArrows: false,
    siblingsNavigation: true,
    navigationDots: false, 
    slideShow: 5000, 
    navigationArrows: true,
    slideMargin: 0,
    skew:-15,

    breakpoints: {
        tablet: {
            maxWidth : 1024,
            slidePercent : 60,
            height:350,
            showCaption: false,
            skew:0
        },
        phone: {
            maxWidth : 600,
            slidePercent : 70,
            height:300,
            skew:0
        }
    }
});
```

I found that the option `slidePercent` changes the size of photos in my slide show, but this is not everything I want. I need my slide to be scaled to fit in the slide bar, and this option only changes it to a percentage of the picture's full size.

How do I do it so that it fits the slide bar?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I find what I need.
On this:

```
imgAlign: 'xMidYMid slice',
```

I put this:

```
imgAlign: 'xMidYFull slice',
```

and

```
slidePercent: 40
```

So. You can lock this. Thank you.